# trigger and player controller error glitch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a cube a trigger with no material renderer and when I played and walked my player into it, my player could not move and Unity said  that "Character.Controller.Move  called on inactive controller" `using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private MoveSettings _settings = null;

```
private Vector3 _moveDirection;
private CharacterController _controller;

private void Awake()
{
    _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

private void Update()
{
    DefaultMovement();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
     _controller.Move(_moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
   //this is where the error is 
}

private void DefaultMovement()
{
    if (_controller.isGrounded)
    {
        Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        if (input.x != 0 && input.y != 0)
        {
            input *= 0.777f;
        }

        _moveDirection.x = input.x * _settings.speed;
        _moveDirection.z = input.y * _settings.speed;
        _moveDirection.y = -_settings.antiBump;

        _moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(_moveDirection);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _moveDirection.y -= _settings.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void Jump()
{
    _moveDirection.y += _settings.jumpForce;
}
```

}`

im also new so please help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is enabled in editor (the little checkbox on every component). If you want to make sure it's enabled add this line to `Awake` method

```
_controller.enabled = true;
```

Comment: im not so sure where to put the code I got it from this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUtusfJHNDM im also kinda new to unity and am not the best with c#

Comment: After this line 
`_controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();`